# Parameterized class vs parameterized method

Tags: java, class, parameterized

```
public class ExplicitTypeSpecification {

    static void f(Map<Integer, String> map){}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        New c = new New();
        f(c.map());
    }
}

class New <K, V>{
    Map<K, V> map(){
        return new HashMap<K, V>();
    }
}
```

This code compiles with no errors.

Then, we make some change in class New:

```
class New {
    <K, V>Map<K, V> map(){
        return new HashMap<K, V>();
    }
}
```

We have parameterized just the method `map()`, but not the whole class. But in this case a **compile error occures** at line `f(c.map());` :

```
java:  f(java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>) in
Generics.ExplicitTypeSpecification.ExplicitTypeSpecification cannot be applied to
(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)*
```

We can point explicit types `f(c.<Integer, String>map());` but I'm interested in *Why we get a compile error?*.

In both cases method `map()` returns `Map<Object, Object>` object,  but in first case we get just a warning of unchecked assignment.

**Question**: why at the second case we have more strict type checking?

**What is the dirrefence** between `new HashMap()` and new `HashMap<Object, Object>()` ? Answer for this problem solves it.

Comment: Interesting finding, especially since `Map<Integer, String> map = c.map(); f(map);` does compile. I think it has something to do with the compiler's ability to guess the correct values for `K` and `V`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are using the raw type `New` (rather than `New<Integer, String>`) so all generic type-checking is disabled. This works as a compatibility mode for old (Java 1.4) code.

Comment: But in the second case I'm using the raw type `New` also. I've just changed class and method parameterizing. My question is why generic type-checking is enabled in this case?

Comment: In the second case, `New` is not generic, so it's just one type, there is no raw type etc. So the compiler does not disable generic-type checking. Instead it tries to infer the generic type for the return type of `c.map()` automatically and fails. Use `Map<Integer, String> map = c.map();` to see automatic inference working.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the type parameters, backwards compatibility with Java 1.4 will suppose that you want "Object". Also, you will get a warning about this.

So your function is equivalent to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    New c = new New();
    f(c.<Object, Object>map());
}
```

And then you get an error saying that you are trying to use the value `Map<Object, Object>` where a parameter `Map<Integer, String>` is expected.

Note: `Map<Integer, String>` is **not** a subtype of `Map<Object, Object>`.

Comment: You are right. **But** if you use **parameterized class** (not parameterized method) - the code in the top, you **don't get error**. Notice, in this case method map() also returns `Map<Object, Object>` because object New is raw and method f() gets this object as a parameter when it really needs `Map<Integer, String>`.